# OpenFire and GCM communication

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, openfire

Currently I am implementing XMPP chatting functionality with Smack library and OpenFire XMPP server. My goal is to merge the XMPP chatting functionality with GCM, since I've read that improves battery efficiency among other benefits.

Everything seems to be pretty straightforward, but one thing. 
I still don't understand how will my app server communicate with the GCM Cloud Connection Server. I do know how to create cURL scripts in PHP and communicate with PayPal servers, since this is a functionality in my app.

I've read that for every XMPP stanza, my app server(which I assume could be OpenFire) needs to send an ACK message to GCM Cloud Connection Server. How is my app server supposed to react when it receives this GCM XMPP stanzas. Should i create a PHP script and host it on my app server? How should I program this server to server communication? Should use PHP scripts on OpenFire with cURL commands and request a transfer?

Any clarification would be appreciated,

Thanks